# Hashed password used for encryption and for user authentication at the same time

Tags: authentication, passwords, password-hashing, password-based-encryption

As I am fairly new to cryptography, I would like to understand how to, in a simple way, implement a system that would achieve the following: the user would have to setup a password, which would then be used to:

**1.)** encrypt the data provided by the user and save it in an encrypted form
and **2.)** to authenticate the user when using the system the next time and decrypt his data.

When searching for viable solutions I found the following two approaches:

**a.)** The password is hashed and the hash is later used to authenticate the user. The combination of the plain text password and its hash is used to generate a key for the encryption and decryption.

**b.)** The password is hashed and a key is derived from its hash to encrypt the data. The authentication is solved by comparing some know plain text to a part of the decrypted data. If there is a match, the user entered the correct password.

I would be grateful for a simple and clear explanation.

I would be also thankful for any references on this specific topic.

Comment: Where did you see both? They are not good approaches since the user may want to change the passwords. You create a  random encryption key per file, and encrypt the key with the key-encryption key generated from password like PBKDFDF2 or better Argon2id. You can see [here in more detail](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75022/18298). When data at rest, the files are protected with random keys and only your password can open it. A good password like from dicewire is recommended.

Comment: @kelalaka Can you please explain how to also solve the user authentication part with the same password. Thank you.

Comment: It is just the standard password hashing [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/86735). You have one password and separate the domains by salt and info.

Comment: Do NOT send everything that is needed for decryption to any server, do decryption locally. Otherwise a compromised server can intercept it and decrypt eveything.